# Data Scraping: Integrate Scrapy [python library to build spiders] with pupeteer- or playwright-extra [JS headless browser automation]

Tags: javascript, python, scrapy, puppeteer, playwright

I am currently developing multiple scrapers that should be maintained for the next couple of years. My typcial approach to traverse large pages is to use [scrapy](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/), a well maintained python framework to build scrapers.

Yet for some of my current targets, I am running into typical barriers like cloudflare, recaptchas, etc., even when using sensible defaults for my user-agent, concurrency, and also integrating with scrapy splash to render JS for the pages.

I played around a bit with two wrappers for Javscript browser automation, [pupeteer-extra](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) and [playwright-extra](https://github.com/berstend/puppeteer-extra/tree/master/packages/playwright-extra) as they offer well working plugins to deal with cloudflare and recaptchas and an array of other challenges.

However, scrapy offers strong benefits in terms of page traversal and using different strategies for interacting with pages and extracting data from different types of pages.

So my question is two-fold:

1. Is there a solution that has implemented playwright- or pupeteer-extra as a plugin to use with scrapy? I am aware of [scrapy-playwright](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-playwright), but specifically need to use the other drop-in plugins for playwright.
2. If there is not anything implemented, is there an option to call a javascript function to handle the requests from python?

Also, I am really happy for any feedback or tips to make this work that I might not have considered yet.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: If what your looking for doesn't already exist, then forking scrapy playwright and extending it to include the missing plugins would be an option

Comment: Thanks, @Alexander - forking and extending would be an option. I am currently trying to hack my way around it to not have the overhead of taking a deep dive into all of the code bases to wrap my head around how to do it - yet, if you have any pointers for where to start and how to do it, I am thankful for any input.